# Programmatically adding captions to Google+ image share in Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I have the following code in Android that programmatically adds a set of photos to a post that will be shared on Google+:

```
private void shareToGooglePlus() {
  // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
  PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this);

  for (String imageFilename : imageList) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imageFilename));
    share.addStream(imageUri);
  }

  share.setText("My images");
  share.setType("image/jpeg");

  startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(), 0);
}
```

Since I have a bunch of different images, I would like to add captions to each to describe what is in each picture.  However, I can't seem to find a way to do that in with PlusShare.Builder.  Does anyone know if it is possible and how to do it?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done with PlusShare - the text refers to the primary post only.